# Do I need to have a license agreement with Apple if my iPhone app uses Bonjour?

Tags: iphone, ios, licensing, bonjour

I have an iPhone app which allows multiple iPhones to connect to each other and send messages. The app uses Bonjour and makes use of some of the CF Networking classes to publish, discover and connect to Bonjour services. My app does not display the bonjour logo or anything like that. It simply uses some networking classes to utilize bonjour so that multiple iPhones within the same WiFi network can connect to each other and send messages to one another. Do I need to get a special Bonjour license from Apple if my app simply makes use of some of these Netowrking classes or do these licenses only apply to you if you want to display the bonjour logo or distribute bonjour itself along with your application?

Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any licensing agreements with Apple. Bonjour is a service that Apple provides, much like HTTP or SMB is.

**UPDATE**:
Some addition info from Wikipedia.

> Bonjour is released under a terms-of-limited-use license by Apple. It
>   is freeware for clients, though developers and software companies who
>   wish to redistribute it as part of a software package or use the
>   Bonjour logo may need a licensing agreement.

Still means that you do not, unless you wish to distribute the software (Bonjour) itself or use the logo. Which you both do not.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's kind of what I thought was the case but glad to hear someone else confirming it!